# How to write Typescript type for React setState-like function

Tags: typescript

I have a function similar to React's `setState` but a little less generic as I know the shape of the state.

Like react I want to either pass a state object in, or accept a callback which passes state in and returns the next state:

```
setState({ ...state, fruit: 'apple' })
setState(s => ({ ...s, fruit: 'apple' }))
```

However I can't get the type right:

```
type State = {
    fruit: string;
}

type SetStateStatic = (nextState: State) => void;
type SetStateCallback = (callback: (state: Readonly<State>) => State) => void;
type SetState = SetStateStatic | SetStateCallback;

function SomeComponent({ setState, state }: { state: State, setState: SetState }) {
    // SetStateStatic
    setState({ ...state, fruit: 'apple' }) // Should work
    setState({ ...state, fruit: 'apple', disallowed: true }) // Shouldn't work, `disallowed` is not on State

    // SetStateCallback
    setState(s => ({ ...s, fruit: 'apple' })) // Should work
    setState(s => ({ ...s, fruit: 'apple', disallowed: true })) // Shouldn't work, `disallowed` is not on State
}
```

Here's a [REPL (playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=107&pln=16&pc=111#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQVtQGYCcBXAS2AC4oBnYfYgOwHMBuDAXww1ElgmDkQj9gxAMZRUACjoQAHnwRIKQiAEpxAPigA3APbEAJiy7QYvZQGF4AGysAjeCIDW4qBJHW7DxxQnUBFACUIeH0dOisQAB5ldTVkTWU4zV0DI3ATMwUUHnkBIVEoAB8ciw97JxYMXEI6EWEw2B0AWwhzZrAwiDpgCTQqTIEAGiosqFYKPr9FWCzhygHp01ykMbVMHCgAek2SrPyRLBx55YheqAA6S6mIYYIScigAcngwMCsIR9WtnZgACx1CFZ9FAAO46fCOQ7YY7KM6Xc7XW5EUgUZ6vd6PYb6YiUDw6EEQfQUGiEaCsNTbWD-QH6OiPYCg8GOYYAA2xuJs%20MJLKgOKgdB0DIayg4G0pS1KNnKkI2MKyvg0rj68MoSPuqJebw%20qwpP2pQMZEKh-ROCviSouVzVKKemoxWJxeIJRKgJLJKl1VIBQLpDLBENZ7Kd3N5lH5gqgwqybAwQA) with the above code.

The code above results in not being assignable/finding a match to the type on each line. How can I write the correct type for the setState function? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
type State = {
   fruit: string;
 };

type Callback = (s: State) => State;
type SetState = (param: State | Callback) => void;

function SomeComponent({ setState, state }: { state: State, setState: SetState 
 }) {
// param: object
setState({ ...state, fruit: 'apple' }) // Should work
setState({ ...state, fruit: 'apple', disallowed: true }) // Shouldn't work, `disallowed` is not on State

// param: callback
setState(s => ({ ...s, fruit: 'apple' })) // Should work
// can't prevent additional properties here because excess property check
// kicks in only when you pass object literals
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks
setState(s => ({ ...s, fruit: 'apple', disallowed: true })) // Shouldn't work, `disallowed` is not on State
```

}

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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

Comment: Ah yes of course thanks, also +1 on the explanation on excess prop check